# js - smoothing movement of a div

Tags: javascript

im just a beginner with js
i have this code and it works fine

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >=800) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "0px");
    } else {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "33px");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

all i need here to make it smooth
or pixel by pixel
like this but simple

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >=700) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "0px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=800) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "1px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=900) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "2px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1000) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "3px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1100) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "4px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1200) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "5px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1300) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "6px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1400) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "7px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1500) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "8px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1600) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "9px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1700) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "10px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1800) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "11px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=1900) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "12px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2000) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "13px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2100) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "14px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2200) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "16px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2300) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "17px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2400) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "18px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2500) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "19px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2600) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "20px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2700) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "21px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2800) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "22px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=2900) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "23px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3000) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "24px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3100) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "25px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3200) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "26px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3300) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "27px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3400) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "28px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3500) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "29px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3600) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "30px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3700) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "31px");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >=3800) {$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "32px");
    } else{$("#ascrail2001").css("margin-top", "33px");
    }
});
```

by the way the above code is not working as i excpect
thanks in advance

Comment: Try to read the documentation of .animate() with a special easing http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: thanks Alexi tried animate but its not working.
i write this cod because i setup wp nicescroll  for html and it makes the scroll bar track as a div, but i need this div margin top:33px
when i write this css the scroll thumb go down out of viewport

Answer (score 0):

That is a very bad way to handle animations, since multiple scroll would fire multiple overlapping events.

You better check jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to let jQuery handle the animation.

Example of correct implementation

```
$(item).stop().animate({
    top: '100px'; //You can make this dynamic
});
```

Comment: sorry but .animate not working with nicescroll script

Comment: You didn't specify that you were using the nicescroll library. You should provide a complete script of your working case to make us able to help

Comment: i am sorry i wrote it in the comment above with Alex